# C++ macros - define " character

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I know that this is absolutely not important, BUT I would like to know how to macro the start/end of a string. For a joke of course :)
If I try to define " as e.g. STRING, `#define STRING "`, I get the following warning:
`warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]   #define STRING "`

Is there any way how I can define this??

Comment: The C++ Preprocessor does *token* substitution.  That's an incomplete *token*.  Probably won't work as desired.  When I ran into this kind of problem, I used a different (atypical of the normal toolchain) preprocessor, which was **Python**, in order to get the preprocessing that I had desired.